# Format of Super Attribute used in Magento table 'sales_flat_quote_item_option'

Tags: magento

I want to extract the product attribute option value in magento. The value store in the table like

```
a:2:{i:137;s:2:"20";i:138;s:2:"22";}
```

How to traverse this value, and what is the format

Answer (score 0):

this is serialize formart. For more infomations please read here http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php